# White_bg.jpg and 10329

Tags: android

I was problem with my android phone a file white_bg.jpg always have in root directory i  try to remove but a few minutes this file create and show in my gallery , another problem is 10329 app run  8% of my battery is using . This is an virus ?

Android 7 
Galaxy s6

Comment: Looks like your question might be a better suit at the [Android enthusiasts](https://android.stackexchange.com/) community, this site is for programming related questions only, you can try to look for answers there.

Comment: welcome to SO. this Site is for programming related question and answer